# tomcat startup.sh not working

Tags: tomcat

I download  tomcat 6.0.24 and install java set environment variables for java and catalina home and check them they are correct but when i try start tomcat with startup.sh  i get setclasspath.sh
This file is needed to run this program    ,i think it result from permission and checkfile  permissions but every thing ok after i googled and find a solution telling me that raplace basedir and catalinahome  enviroment variables in setclasspath.sh with their actual values ,but i want to know what is the source cause of this error.

By the way,if a kill tomcat and run startup.sh it give this output but tomcat actually running ,when i try localhost:8080

Comment: Sorry this is my error i setup catalina home wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enviroment variables wrong  in my case catalina_home  sorry for post